# Flask - Send POST request to specific section in the same page

Tags: python, html, post, flask

I'm building a simple web site using `flask`, witch contain one page html `index.html`, and sections : `search`, `about`, `contact`. This sections are not displayed until the user enter to them

I want to send a `POST request` from `index.html/#search` to the same section : `index.html/#search`.

I tried to send it like that :

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def Search():
    _text = request.form['text']
    return render_template('index.html/#search', result=_text)
```

but that didn't work, and I get this error :

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html/#search

I tried to pass `search` as parameter :

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def Search():
    _text = request.form['text']
    return render_template('index.html', id="search", result=_text)
```

but when I run it didn't works because it takes me  to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/search` (witch displayed the `index.html` page) while I want to go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/#search`.

This is my *index.html* page:

```
<article id="search">
   <h2 class="major">search</h2>
   <form method="post" action="Search">
       <label for="text">Text</label>
       <input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="write any thing in your mind :p" required/>
       <input name="search" type="submit" value="See Polarity" class="special" />
       <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
   </form>

   <!-- result search -->
   {% if result : %}
       <p>{{ result }}</p>
   {% endif %}
</article>
```

Comment: the browser display : *The method is not allowed for the requested URL.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` represents an anchor on an existing page, not a new page.

Similarly, your syntax of :

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
```

Would create a new route to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/search` . If you want it to render `index.html` and then jump to the `search` anchor you should have it render `index.html` as you've done it, include the `_anchor` attribute. It would look like:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def Search():
    if request.method == 'GET'
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:      
        _text = request.form['text']
        return render_template('index.html', _anchor="search", result=_text)
```

Comment: When I write : _action = "/"_ the browser display : _The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand._

& when I change it to _action = "#search"_ , it displayed : _The method is not allowed for the requested URL._

Comment: Try leaving action blank. So: `action=""`

Comment: It did take me to _http://127.0.0.1:5000/#search_, but the browser displayed : **Bad Request** : _The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand._

Comment: Check my updated comment. I deleted the first one because I realized I had misunderstood what you wrote.

Comment: witch comment you mean ?

Comment: If you make `action=""` in `index.html`

Comment: Yes, I did see it, & answered you :  it takes me to  **127.0.0.1:5000/#search**, but the browser displayed :  **Bad Request** : _The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand_.

Comment: That's tough to say, but I suspect it's something with the form you're submitting.

This may not be the cause, but you don't need a colon at the end of your if statement in jinja, so 
    {% if result : %}
        <p>{{ result }}</p>
    {% endif %}

Can be:

    {% if result %}
        <p>{{ result }}</p>
    {% endif %}

Comment: I get the same result :(

Comment: I think that the problem is because i'm sending the data to the same page, because it works for me when I try to send it to a new page, what do you think?

Comment: I found the problem, I was writing *_text = request.form['txt']*, I don't know how that happend ! Thank you a lot :)